# An alternating product/sum Fibonacci-like sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Starting from reals $a_1, a_2$, define a sequence $S(a_1, a_2)$

$$a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, \ldots, a_{k-1}, a_{k}, a_{k+1}, a_{k+2}, \ldots \;,$$

so that, given the sequence up to its $k$-th element, $k \ge 2$ even,
the next two elements are defined by
\begin{eqnarray}
a_{k+1} &=& a_{k-1} &\times& a_k \\
a_{k+2} &=& a_k &+& a_{k+1}
\end{eqnarray}

For example, the first ten elements of $S(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$
are:
$$
\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}
   ,-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{3}{4}
   ,\frac{3}{16},-\frac{9}{16}
   ,-\frac{27}{256},-\frac{171}{256}
   ,\frac{4617}{65536},-\frac{39159}{65536},\ldots \;.
$$
I wanted to explore mixing multiplication and addition.
So this is like the Fibonacci sequence, except that the steps
alternate between  multiplication and addition.

Two questions, one specific, one general.

> ***Q1***. Numerically, the odd elements of $S(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$
> head to $0$, and the even elements head to $\approx -0.622748$.
> You can see in the list of rationals above that the
> denominators are
> $2^m$ where
> $m = 2^ {\lfloor (k-1)/2 \rfloor }$.
> But the pattern in the numerators seems difficult to see.
> How can the even and odd limits be proven,
> either by explicit calculation of the numerators, or by identifying
> dominate terms that lead to proofs of convergence?

> ***Q2***. For which $a_1, a_2$ do both the even and odd elements of $S(a_1, a_2)$ converge?

It seems the convergence region in the $(a_1, a_2)$ plane includes the two
diagonally opposite squares
\begin{eqnarray}
a_1 \in (0,1) &\;\;\mathrm{and}\;& a_2 \in (-1,0)\\
a_1 \in (-1,0) &\;\;\mathrm{and}\;& a_2 \in (0,1)
\end{eqnarray}
but is significantly broader.
For example, $S(2, -\frac{1}{3})$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Study separately the sequence of even indices and odd indices. It's easy to see that for the sequence $S(\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{2})$ they satisfies:

The odd indices:
$$o_1=\frac{1}{2},\;o_2=-\frac{1}{4},\; o_{n+2}=o_{n+1}^2\left(1+\frac{1}{o_n}\right)$$

The even indices:

$$e_1=-\frac{1}{2},\;e_2=-\frac{3}{4},\; e_{n+2}=e_{n+1}(e_{n+1}-e_n+1)$$